# Why wouldn't Lady Brienne strike down the Red Woman once she realized who she was?

Tags: game-of-thrones

One thing bothering me is how nonchalant Lady Brienne was upon meeting the Red Woman in Castle Black this season in the show.  She travelled across the world and risked death to finally kill the man who had ordered the unholy hit on her beloved Renly.

Why would she be OK *at all* with being near or working alongside the woman whose shadow magic had enabled this hit and who had advised it in the first place?

Comment: Because Brienne is honorable. She understands whatever Mel did was on command of Stannis Baratheon. The tool is not to be blamed, the man who uses the tool is to be blamed.

Comment: I'd not go as far as saying that Brienne would like Mel but I suppose she would understand

Comment: I agree that Brienne is honorable, but the line is not quite so black/white here.  Melissandre is not an unthinking tool, but a competent and willing advisor and co-conspirator.  Can you cite an example in the character's history where she displayed similar behavior or said something to that effect?  (supporting the concept of the tool not being to blame, but the man using the tool being to blame)

Comment: If She had actually said that, I would have posted this as answer. But there are other characters who display such attitude. E.g. Prince Oberyn tells Tyrion that Even if Gregor killed his sister, orders still came from Tywin Lannister. Which is why he wants him. Tyrion however says that in the end all Orders came from Robert, which was Tywin's position as well.

Comment: Brienne does not know the capacity in which Mel served or of her influence on Stannis. From an outsiders perspective, Mel would appear to be just another person in service of an aristocrat

Comment: Brienne knows that a shadow killed Renly and she also knows that Melissandre is the only one around that can do such magic.  Furthermore, it is said aloud prior to the resurrection of Jon Snow.  I don't think that's true at all. (that she didn't know it was Melissandre)

Comment: Which makes Mel the tool. It does not in anyway imply that Mel proposed that scheme or influenced Stannis to go through it (Which was infact the case). Brienne does not know it. All she possibly knows is that Mel created the shadow to kill Renly on command of Stannis.

Comment: Also I recall when Renly died, Brienne said this "It was Stannis. I will kill him. I swear it. I swear it. I swear it". So from the beginning, Stannis was the culprit in her mind.

Comment: From the looks that were exchanged, I got the distinct impression that as soon as they met, Brienne put Melissandre on her "list", and Melissandre knew it. Remember the dig and pointed look about "blood magic"? Speculating: A) Brienne isn't **sure** Melissandre was involved. B) The moment was not appropriate for combat/vengeance/justice. C) Brienne wasn't sure she even *could* kill a powerful sorceress. Compare with Ser Davos who clearly doesn't yet know how Stannis' daughter died (can't remember her name) because that would involve some angry words at least if and when he finds out.

Answer (score 10):

I would think the main reason is that, unlike Stannis, who she already swore to kill and she encountered in opportune fashion in the chaos of a battlefield, where smiting people is considered accepted behavior, she encounters the Red Woman at Castle Black, as a guest/companion/advisor of the Lord Commander who just opened the gates to her and Lady Sansa.  Very different situation.  I think she implied that if the honorable opportunity arose for her to deal with the Red Woman as Stannis was dealt with, she'd take it, but Brienne is nothing, if not honorable.

Answer (score 3):

I think she was waiting for an excuse to do just that. If you watch the episode closely, you'll notice she had her sword in her hand when she told Melissandre and Ser Davos that she was the one that executed Stannis.

It's a very deliberate action on her part, she wanted to provoke them so she can kill them. She is sworn to Sansa, and they are guests of Sansa's brother Jon Snow - killing them would have brought dishonor to Sansa and Jon. If they were to attack her on the other hand... well, obviously, cutting them down would have been perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Jon is Sansa's savior, Melisandre is Jon's guest (and savior), Brienne is Sansa's sworn sword and has promised to obey her. I don't think she'd dishonor Sansa by killing her brother's guest and someone who is serving him in a capacity unknown fully to Brienne. There are unknown consequences. Besides, she may even be thinking that the Red Woman may extend her quite useful brand of protection to Sansa, putting them on the same side, however tenuously. Also, I'm not sure what Brienne thinks of killing a woman.